# Newline chars somehow get added to my strings. And cant remove them

Tags: iphone, objective-c

On some of my strings there seems to be somekind of newline char. I think this is the case because when i do a simple NSLog

```
NSLog(@"Test: %@",aNSMutableString);
```

I would get output like below

```
Test:
I am a String
```

I've tried using

```
[mutableString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

But it does not remove whatever it is thats forcing the newline to happen.

In a string that i parse out from a file which has 4 characters 'm3u8' has 5 chars when I check the length of the new string.

Anybody got an idea of what might be going on?

Thanks
-Code

P.S.
I know I could just zap the first char out of all my strings but it feels like a hack and i still wont know whats going on.

Comment: Wow.  How are you setting `aNSMutableString` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[mutableString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

The above will not directly modify your `mutableString`.  It returns a new autoreleased `NSString` with the characters trimmed.  See [NSString doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSString).

e.x.

```
NSString *trimmedString = [mutableString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"Test: %@", trimmedString);
```

should give you expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Sam 's answer will fix your problem, but I think the origin of your problem is the file source.  Do you know how it is encoded?  Is it part of a download?  My guess is that you have a Windows' file with "\n\r" terminating lines and you are using Unix string tools that are breaking on "\n", thus leaving a leading "\r".

Verify the source of the file and read the document lines with the appropriate encoding.